# Custom fields on ApplicationUser not being saved

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I added some fields to the ApplicationUser class, now when I'm trying to save the user , it only saves the Email , password and phone number because these are some of the originals fields on the IdentityUser class.

First of all, maybe this is related with the issue or not. After I added the fields I added a migration to my project but this migration was coming up empty so I manually type the code to include the new fields, now it feels like somehow EntityFramework doesn't recognize the new fields on my class therefore not saving it.

this is my code for the ApplicationUser class

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;

namespace Domain.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        
        public string FirstName;
        public string LastName;

        public string Photo;
        public string Street;
        public string City;
        public string State;
        public string Country;        

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("CubaViajes", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the method where I create the user and save it

```
        // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                
                var user = new ApplicationUser { 
                    UserName = model.Email, 
                    Email = model.Email,
                    FirstName=model.FirstName,
                    LastName=model.LastName,
                    PhoneNumber=model.Phone,
                    Street=model.Street,
                    City=model.City,
                    State=model.State,
                    Country=model.Country 
                };

                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    //Assign Role to user Here 
                    await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Rol);
                    //Ends Here


                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                    Session["userAdded"] = true;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }
            ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

The user is being successfully saved but is only saving the email, password and phone number, is not persisting the other fields I have .

Edit 1:

I checked the SQL profiler and on the Insert command the new fields are not listed, the same for the select query, only retrieves/saves the defaults one

below is the select query which doesn't include the fields I added

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
    [Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
    [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
go
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You say you did an `Add-Migration`. Did you also follow that up with an `Update-Database`? `Add-Migration` generates the change file, `Update-Database` actually applies it. Has the schema in your DB been updated?

Comment: Yes, I also executed Update-database but only after I had to manually add the model changes in the migration, I can see on the AspNetUsers table that my fields are there

Comment: it feels like somehow my model is not "synchronized" with the table, the columns were added only because I typed it in on the migration

Comment: When you did the `Add-Migration`, you did make sure you targeting the right Assembly? Also set up logging either via `Sql Profiler` or using `Database.Log` on your `DbContext`. So you can see what SQL is being sent to the db.

Comment: Yes, the migration was targeting the right assembly. Using the Sql Profiler I could see that the Insert command and select query doesn't have the fields I added, just the default ones. Also I have my IdentityModel on a separate project where I store all my models and context, just in case this means something

Comment: So to confirm: you did run the migration against the project with the IdentityModel in them right? Not against the client UI project/assembly? A simple way to check is to look in the migrations table in SQL Server and check what assembly name it was configured with. Basically you need to retrace your steps at this point because as per SQL Profiler, the SQL is not being sent to the DB. So you've made some simple mistake (we've all done it) with your EF migrations.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this issue.

I realized that ApplicationUser uses its own context **ApplicationDbContext** and not the same as my other models classes , so I was just applying the migration to the wrong context instead of the one used by ApplicationUser

Comment: You shouldn't need to have two separate `DbContext`s.  Both should be using the same one.

Comment: @BrendanGreen, I found that was the issue with my migrations, but beyond this point I've no idea how to solve this. How can I use just one DbContext when ApplicationUser by default uses its own ApplicationDbContext (IdentityDbContext) and for my other models I have another DbContext which I'm sharing with other mvc 5 projects. any ideas?